# Solve $\iint \exp(\frac{x}{y}) \, dx \, dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Solve 
$$\iint_D \exp\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) \, dx \, dy$$

where $D=\{(x,y): 1\leq y \leq 2, y \leq x \leq y^3 \}$

**My attempt:**

$$\iint_D \exp\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) \, dx \, dy = \int_1^{\sqrt[3]{2}} \int_y^{y^3}  \exp\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) \, dx \, dy + \int_{\sqrt[3]{2}}^2 \int_{y}^2  \exp\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) \, dx \, dy$$

But i dont know how to solve
$$ \int y \exp\left(\frac{2}{y}\right) \, dy$$

Am I doing someting wrong or should we do a change of variable to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In your definitionfor D, you have $1 \le y \le 2$. But in your limits of integration for $dy$ you have 1 and $\sqrt[3]{2}$. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Set up the integral as follows:

$$\int_1^2 dy \, \int_y^{y^3} dx \, e^{x/y} $$

The inner integral is simple

$$\int_y^{y^3} dx \, e^{x/y} = y \left [ e^{x/y}\right ]_y^{y^3}  = y (e^{y^2}-e)$$

This now goes into the outer integral:

$$\int_1^2 dy \, y (e^{y^2}-e) $$

which I think you can get.

Comment: Why should't we separate the integrals? Doesn't it covers more than we need?

Comment: @Giiovanna: maybe it's a language thing, but I have no idea what you are saying.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y+%3C+x+%3C+y%5E3+for+y%3D1+to+2

Comment: I dont know if we can directly integrate from $x=y$ to $x=y^3$

Comment: @Giiovanna: Sure we can; why not?

Comment: Because when $\sqrt[3]{2} \leq y \leq 2$, then $y \leq x \leq 2$

Comment: What's this thing with the cube root?  The interval is $1 \le y \le 2$.  Over this interval, $y \le y^3$.  The given interval is fine.

Comment: Check my wolfram alpha input and see. When $\sqrt[3]{2} \leq y \leq 2$ (and note that$ 1 < \sqrt[3]{2}$), $x$ doesnt goes from $y$ to $y^3$, but goes from $y$ to $2$.

Comment: Please note that @MichaelHardy is saying the exact thing as me.  You need to take a deep breath and start over.

Answer (score 1):

There would be a reason to split it into two parts if one put $x$ on the outside and $y$ on the inside, but as it is, there is none.  When $y\ge1$, then $y^3\ge y$, so $x$ just needs to go from $y$ to $y^3$.
$$
\int_1^2 \left( \int_y^{y^3} \exp\left( \frac x y\right) \, dx \right) \,dy
$$

The inside integral is
$$
\left.y\exp\frac x y \right|_{x:=y}^{x:=y^3} = y\exp y^2 - y\exp 1.
$$
So we have
\begin{align}
\int_1^2 (y e^{y^2} - ey) \, dy & = \int_1^2 e^{y^2} \Big(y \, dy\Big) - \frac{3e}{2} \\[12pt]
& = \int_1^4 e^u \left(\frac12\,du\right) - \frac{3e}{2}
\end{align}
etc.